# how to build activemq source code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, activemq-classic

I downloaded `activemq 5.8` source code, tried to use `maven` to generate an eclipse project. I got 2 errors:

```
[ERROR]     Child module E:\activemq-parent-5.8.0\activemq-amq-store\pom.xml of 
E:\activemq-parent-5.8.0\pom.xml does not exist

[ERROR]     Child module E:\activemq-parent-5.8.0\activemq-all\pom.xml of 
E:\activemq-parent-5.8.0\pom.xml does not exist
```

For sure, the two files didn't contain `pom.xml`. I am not sure whether the two files should be in `activemq-amq-store` and `activemq-all`.

Answer (score 3):

Clone this [project](http://activemq.apache.org/source.html):

> git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq.git

then [building it with maven](http://activemq.apache.org/building.html):

> mvn -Dtest=false -DfailIfNoTests=false clean install